# How to carry with result on recursive operation

Tags: javascript

If I can't pass an integer by reference how I can carry with the result on this function:

```js
function operation(k, n, result) {
  if (k == 0) {
    console.log(n);
    result += n;
    return result;
  } else {
    //the result variable its back to the old value when the recursions goes back
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      operation(k - 1, i, result);
    }
  }
}

console.log('resultado = ', operation(2, 3, 0));
```

I need  to accumulate n value on result when k=0,but result goes back to older  values.I'm not sure about how to make it

Comment: How about `result = operation(k - 1, i, result);`

Comment: Also you need a `return result; ` in the `else` clause.

Comment: what exactly should the function return?

Comment: Pointy's comment is on point (pun intended). You need to get the value of `operation(k - 1, i, result);` but you are not assigning it to anything.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript arguments are passed by value: the `result` parameter is a separate variable in your recursive function's execution context.

As @Pointy remarked in comments you need to assign the return value back to `result`. The idea is to *return* the new value.

That would look like this:

```js
function operation(k, n, result) {
    if (k == 0) {
        result += n;
    } else {
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result = operation(k - 1, i, result);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log('resultado = ', operation(2, 3, 0));
```

Although this works, the more natural way to implement recursion, is to let the recursive call produce a result that is independent from the larger context it is running in: it should not have to know the "result so far". Instead it should return the result as if it was executing the top-level call. It is up to the caller to accumulate the result further.

So with that pattern, you would *not* pass a `result` as argument at all:

```js
function operation(k, n) {
    if (k == 0) return n;
    let result = 0; // we start from scratch
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result += operation(k - 1, i); // note the addition here!
    }
    return result;
}
console.log('resultado = ', operation(2, 3));
```